# Multiple users setup for Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gui, xfce, multiple-users

I'd like to have a cron task that will be launching apps and taking screenshots on Xfce environment and in order not to interfere with that I'd setup another user that will be running with no GUI for other tasks. What would you recommend in order to achieve that? I don't care if one user might access files of the other since they'll both be under my command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second user to run without a GUI unless you *prefer* working from the command line.

In fact, you don't even need them to be distinct users.

If your cron job executes `startx`, the result will be an independent graphical session that is not affected by login through the display manager.

Comment: interesting, I'll check it out